# Where can I find docs on lawsuits filed against a government agency?

Tags: united-states, law, government

While doing some research on my free time I came across an interesting article that had referenced a (public?) document of a lawsuit filed against the NSA.  Due to the number of trolls on the net these days, I entered the doc name ("john doe" vs NSA, place of incident, state, USA) and all I got were a whole bunch of sites HOSTING the doc on their servers, which may have been altered.  Is there a Government site that I could search that would yield my desired doc?

Comment: If this case gets to the Supreme Court, I have some suggestions.  You may want to consider asking on Law.SE.  They will certainly know how to find whatever document.  The downside is that they might not know of a free way to find the document.  They might get it from a paid service.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [PACER](https://www.pacer.gov/).

> Public Access to Court Electronic Records (PACER) is an electronic public access service that allows users to obtain case and docket information online from federal appellate, district, and bankruptcy courts, and the PACER Case Locator. PACER is provided by the Federal Judiciary in keeping with its commitment to providing public access to court information via a centralized service.

Since the NSA is a federal agency, it's a good bet that any lawsuit against it will end up there.  However, without more details, it's impossible to link you to a specific case.

Answer (score -4):

Answering my own question due to my lack of info given in the description.  Plus it's not really one that can be ANSWERED (at least to my satisfaction) because any sites that you all would refer to would have to be from an official, or at least VERY credible, government-type server...and https://www.nsa.gov is the only winner here, so any other sites would be labeled merely as SUGGESTIONS rather than an answer to my Q.

Comment: While answering your own question is encouraged, answering an unanswerable question doesn't have much value.  You should either edit the question to specify that you're looking for official government sources, or just remove the question altogether.

Comment: PACER - https://www.pacer.gov/  is a government website.  In the footer you can see this.  "This site is maintained by the Administrative Office of the U.S. Courts, PACER Service Center. The purpose of this site is to provide information about locating and filing cases in U.S. federal courts."